# Reset Time element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a time element which needs to be able to reset to its blank value "--:--:--"

```
<input type="time" id="des_time_input" name="time_input" size="20" placeholder="Time..." value="">
```

The script is this.

```
defaultVal = document.getElementById('des_time_input').defaultValue;
 document.getElementById('des_time_input').value = defaultVal;
```

If I put a value in the element the script works but I need to default value to be blank.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your `input` value to `''`, resetting it :

```js
function reset(){
  document.getElementById("des_time_input").value = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="des_time_input" name="time_input" size="20" placeholder="Time..." value="">
<button onclick="reset();">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I just realised after posting the question that I had the IDs messed up...... so much for spending an afternoon... but thanks #Zenoo your answer is correct.

I used the document.getElementById('des_time_input').value = null;